# How much byte a long variable takes if int value is stored in it?

Tags: java

I am storing an integer value in long variable ut if I am giving value greater than int range then it is saying that "literal of type int is greater than range".

The range of integer is 2147483648 to 2147483647

So when I am storing

```
long l=2147483647;
```

then it is running fine

But when I am storing

```
long l=2147483648;
```

then it is giving compile time error as "literal of type int is greater than range"

So I want to  know that if I am storing `long l=2147483647;` 
i.e. value of int range in long variable then does it uses 32 bit or 64 bit to store it.

Also if it uses 64 bit then why it is giving error for `long l=2147483648;`

Comment: You may need 2147483648**L**.

Comment: Sir, i know that with L it will work but I want to know that if I dont use L then if I store an integervalue in long than how does java treats it. Does it treats it as an integer variable and assigns 32 bit storage or 64bit storage

Comment: so will java not convert the integer literal to a long literal even if  we are storing it in long variable

Comment: Basic types take the same amount no matter what you store in them. The error message is not related to this in any way. So the literal takes as much the literal type defines, the variable takes as much as the variable type defines.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: No, for an `int` literal being assigned to a `long` variable, the conversion is performed at compile time. In your example of `int i = 123; long l = i;` *that* conversion is performed at execution time.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that when a `long` stores a value that is within the range of `int`, it will use 32 bits to store it. This is not true.

Java Language Specification Section 4.2 Primitive Types and Values

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and *64-bit* signed two's-complement integers, respectively.

You got the compiler error because the integer literal `2147483648` cannot be used in that context. The error has nothing to do with the size of `long`.

Section 3.10

> All decimal literals from 0 to 2147483647 may appear anywhere an int
>   literal may appear. The decimal literal 2147483648 may appear only as
>   the operand of the unary minus operator `-` (§15.15.4).
>
> It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears
>   anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; or if
>   a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648